# Mongodb 3.2 : mongodb aggregation with $project before $lookup

Tags: mongodb

I've a problem, actually I'm trying to join different collections for some operation, but I'm not able to get the result as both "BatchInfo" and "UserInfo" is coming as null.

The reason I'm doing "project" first is because I want to take out "Batch Id" and "User Id" from respective objects and then apply in respective "lookup" "foreignField". Also, I'm using mongo 3.2.

```
db.getCollection('coursecompletedfeedbacks').aggregate([

    {

        $project: {

           "BATCH" : 1,

           "FEEDBACK" : 1,

           "USER" : 1,

           "batchId" : "$BATCH._id",

           "userId" : "$USER._id"

        }

    },

    {

        $lookup:{

            from: "batches",           

            localField: "batchId",         

            foreignField: "_id",   

            as: "BatchInfo"           

        }

    },

    {

        $lookup:{

            from: "users",           

            localField: "userId",         

            foreignField: "_id",   

            as: "UserInfo"           

        }

    }

])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

```
db.getCollection('coursecompletedfeedbacks').aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: "batches",           
            let: { bId: "$BATCH._id" },          
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $eq: ["$_id", "$$bId"]
                        }
                    }
                },
            ],
            as: "BatchInfo"           
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: "users",           
            let: { uId: "$USER._id" },      
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $eq: ["$_id", "$$uId"]
                        }
                    }
                },
            ],   
            as: "UserInfo"           
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
           "BatchInfo" : 1,
           "UserInfo" : 1,
           ""FEEDBACK" : 1,
        }
    },
])
```

Comment: Hi Jitendra, I tried your answer but I'm getting error saying : "errmsg" : "arguments to $lookup must be strings, let: { bId: \"$BATCH._id\" } "

Comment: Sorry, but above query will work only with MongoDB 3.6 as this syntax of lookup introduced with version 3.6. If you can upgrade your version then please do it as it will be very helpful further to query various complicated data.

Comment: That's the problem, I've solution with v3.4 as well but with v3.2 unable to find one :(